# mysql stored procedure return value is not correct

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Mysql stored procedure returns only one same value even when the parameters changed. 
If I run this

```
CALL gain_loss_indi('CNX','day1','2015-11-10')
```

the result will be `@clvalue=700.00` and if i change the first parameter `CALL gain_loss_indi('NV20','day1','2015-11-10')` the return value is still same as the previous result `@clvalue=700.00` but it should be `@clvalue=50.00` 
. Please help me to solve this. Given below is my stored procedure.

```
        DELIMITER ||
    CREATE PROCEDURE gain_loss_indi(
    IN Symbol VARCHAR(50),
    IN Period VARCHAR(20),
    IN date_ad datetime
    )
    BEGIN
         IF Period ='day1' THEN
      SET @clvalue := (SELECT (SELECT CLOSE_PRICE FROM cash_indices_data WHERE SYMBOL=Symbol AND date_added <= DATE_SUB(date_ad, INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,1) as clday1);
         ELSEIF Period ='week1' THEN
        SET @clvalue := (SELECT (SELECT CLOSE_PRICE FROM cash_indices_data WHERE SYMBOL=Symbol AND date_added <= DATE_SUB(date_ad, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,1) as clweek1);
         ELSEIF Period ='week2' THEN
         SET @clvalue := (SELECT (SELECT CLOSE_PRICE FROM cash_indices_data WHERE SYMBOL=Symbol AND date_added <= DATE_SUB(date_ad, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,1) as clweek2);
         ELSEIF Period ='month1' THEN
         SET @clvalue :=(SELECT (SELECT CLOSE_PRICE FROM cash_indices_data WHERE SYMBOL=Symbol AND date_added <= DATE_SUB(date_ad, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,1) as clmonth1);
         ELSEIF Period ='month3' THEN
         SET @clvalue :=(SELECT (SELECT CLOSE_PRICE FROM cash_indices_data WHERE SYMBOL=Symbol AND date_added <= DATE_SUB(date_ad, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,1) as clmonth3);
         ELSEIF Period ='month6' THEN
         SET @clvalue :=(SELECT (SELECT CLOSE_PRICE FROM cash_indices_data WHERE SYMBOL=Symbol AND date_added <= DATE_SUB(date_ad, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,1) as clmonth6);
         ELSEIF Period ='month9' THEN
         SET @clvalue :=(SELECT (SELECT CLOSE_PRICE FROM cash_indices_data WHERE SYMBOL=Symbol AND date_added <= DATE_SUB(date_ad, INTERVAL 9 MONTH) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,1) as clmonth9);
         ELSEIF Period ='year1' THEN
        SET @clvalue := (SELECT (SELECT CLOSE_PRICE FROM cash_indices_data WHERE SYMBOL=Symbol AND date_added <= DATE_SUB(date_ad, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,1) as clyear1);
         END IF;

        SELECT @clvalue;

    END ||

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: simply (as step 1) run directly corresponding SQL with all these parameters and see what is the result in both cases.

Comment: Or provide us with sample data on which the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @ mitkosoft when the sql run directly with all parameters its working fine and the result is correct. But I want to call the function for each one.

Comment: Thanks, Please upvote the question also.